# data highly skewed and values range is too large

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-visualization

i'am trying to rescale and normalize my dataset
my data is highly skewed and also the values range is too large which affecting my models performance
i've tried using robustscaler() and powerTransformer() and yet no improvement

below you can see the boxplot and kde plot and also skew() test of my data

[image][image]

```
df_test.agg(['skew', 'kurtosis']).transpose()
```

[image]

the data is financial data so it can take a large range of values ( they are not really ouliers)

Comment: welcome to SO. For future references, do not post images of your data. Instead, post data. It makes it so much easier to test solutions that fit your needs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data, there are several ways to handle this. There is however a function that will help you handle skew data by doing a preliminary transformation to your normalization effort.

Go to this repo (https://github.com/datamadness/Automatic-skewness-transformation-for-Pandas-DataFrame) and download the functions `skew_autotransform.py` and `TEST_skew_autotransform.py`. Put this function in the same folder as your code. Use it in the same way as in this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

from skew_autotransform import skew_autotransform

exampleDF = pd.DataFrame(load_boston()['data'], columns = load_boston()['feature_names'].tolist())

transformedDF = skew_autotransform(exampleDF.copy(deep=True), plot = True, exp = False, threshold = 0.5)

print('Original average skewness value was %2.2f' %(np.mean(abs(exampleDF.skew()))))
print('Average skewness after transformation is %2.2f' %(np.mean(abs(transformedDF.skew()))))
```

It will return several graphs and measures of skewness of each variable, but most importantly a transformed dataframe of the handled skewed data:

Original data:

```
 CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM   AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  \
0    0.00632  18.0   2.31   0.0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900  1.0  296.0   
1    0.02731   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671  2.0  242.0   
2    0.02729   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671  2.0  242.0   
3    0.03237   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622  3.0  222.0   
4    0.06905   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622  3.0  222.0   
..       ...   ...    ...   ...    ...    ...   ...     ...  ...    ...   
501  0.06263   0.0  11.93   0.0  0.573  6.593  69.1  2.4786  1.0  273.0   
502  0.04527   0.0  11.93   0.0  0.573  6.120  76.7  2.2875  1.0  273.0   
503  0.06076   0.0  11.93   0.0  0.573  6.976  91.0  2.1675  1.0  273.0   
504  0.10959   0.0  11.93   0.0  0.573  6.794  89.3  2.3889  1.0  273.0   
505  0.04741   0.0  11.93   0.0  0.573  6.030  80.8  2.5050  1.0  273.0   

     PTRATIO       B  LSTAT  
0       15.3  396.90   4.98  
1       17.8  396.90   9.14  
2       17.8  392.83   4.03  
3       18.7  394.63   2.94  
4       18.7  396.90   5.33  
..       ...     ...    ...  
501     21.0  391.99   9.67  
502     21.0  396.90   9.08  
503     21.0  396.90   5.64  
504     21.0  393.45   6.48  
505     21.0  396.90   7.88  

[506 rows x 13 columns]
```

and the tranformed data:

```
      CRIM         ZN  INDUS           CHAS       NOX     RM         AGE  \
0   -6.843991   1.708418   2.31 -587728.314092 -0.834416  6.575  201.623543   
1   -4.447833 -13.373080   7.07 -587728.314092 -1.092408  6.421  260.624267   
2   -4.448936 -13.373080   7.07 -587728.314092 -1.092408  7.185  184.738608   
3   -4.194470 -13.373080   2.18 -587728.314092 -1.140400  6.998  125.260171   
4   -3.122838 -13.373080   2.18 -587728.314092 -1.140400  7.147  157.195622   
..        ...        ...    ...            ...       ...    ...         ...   
501 -3.255759 -13.373080  11.93 -587728.314092 -0.726384  6.593  218.025321   
502 -3.708638 -13.373080  11.93 -587728.314092 -0.726384  6.120  250.894792   
503 -3.297348 -13.373080  11.93 -587728.314092 -0.726384  6.976  315.757117   
504 -2.513274 -13.373080  11.93 -587728.314092 -0.726384  6.794  307.850962   
505 -3.643173 -13.373080  11.93 -587728.314092 -0.726384  6.030  269.101967   

          DIS       RAD       TAX        PTRATIO             B     LSTAT  
0    1.264870  0.000000  1.807258   32745.311816  9.053163e+08  1.938257  
1    1.418585  0.660260  1.796577   63253.425063  9.053163e+08  2.876983  
2    1.418585  0.660260  1.796577   63253.425063  8.717663e+08  1.640387  
3    1.571460  1.017528  1.791645   78392.216639  8.864906e+08  1.222396  
4    1.571460  1.017528  1.791645   78392.216639  9.053163e+08  2.036925  
..        ...       ...       ...            ...           ...       ...  
501  0.846506  0.000000  1.803104  129845.602554  8.649562e+08  2.970889  
502  0.776403  0.000000  1.803104  129845.602554  9.053163e+08  2.866089  
503  0.728829  0.000000  1.803104  129845.602554  9.053163e+08  2.120221  
504  0.814408  0.000000  1.803104  129845.602554  8.768178e+08  2.329393  
505  0.855697  0.000000  1.803104  129845.602554  9.053163e+08  2.635552  

[506 rows x 13 columns]
```

After having done this, normalize the data if you need to.

**Update**

Given the ranges of some of your data, you need to probably do this case by case and by trial and error. There are several normalizers you can use to test different approaches. I'll give you a few of them on an example columns,

```
exampleDF = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=",")
exampleDF = pd.DataFrame(exampleDF['LiabilitiesNoncurrent_total'])

     LiabilitiesNoncurrent_total
count                 6.000000e+02
mean                  8.865754e+08
std                   3.501445e+09
min                  -6.307000e+08
25%                   6.179232e+05
50%                   1.542650e+07
75%                   3.036085e+08
max                   5.231900e+10
```

**Sigmoid**

Define the following function

```
def sigmoid(x):
    e = np.exp(1)
    y = 1/(1+e**(-x))
    return y
```

and  do

```
df = sigmoid(exampleDF.LiabilitiesNoncurrent_total)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

'LiabilitiesNoncurrent_total' had 'positive' skewness of 8.85

The transformed one has a skewness of -2.81

**Log+1 Normalization**

Another approach is to use a logarithmic function and then to normalize.

```
def normalize(column):
    upper = column.max()
    lower = column.min()
    y = (column - lower)/(upper-lower)
    return y

df = np.log(exampleDF['LiabilitiesNoncurrent_total'] + 1)
df_normalized = normalize(df)
```

The skewness is reduced by approxiamately the same amount.

I would opt for this last option rather than a sigmoidal approach. I also suspect that you can apply this solution to all your features.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried minmaxscaler(), robustscaler(), standardscaler()

Comment: In my case the data is not only highly skewed and also the range of values is too large ( -100M to +100M)

Comment: @yassinesfayhi Can you share a sample of your data? Might help to test things on actual data.

Comment: Okay I'll but how can I do it and it's 500 rows enough as a sample?

Comment: It should be enough if it is representative of your data (in other words, if you haven't sorted it in any way).

Comment: here you go please let me know if got the sample or not 
easyupload.io/cip1bl

Comment: So, I've tried with you data and the method works well. Do you really need to normalize all columns?

Comment: yes , i've tried it and it didn't work well o got this as a result                                 Original average skewness value was 9.76
Average skewness after transformation is 36.35

Comment: what should i do